# How to solve responseJSON: {error: "invalid_request", error_description: "Missing required parameter: code"}

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-api

I'm trying to upload files to Google Drive from my web application with Vuejs and Javascript, but when I send the request it marks that error.
I checked the value of variable **code** and is **null**, even the variable **window.location.search** is an empty string, but I don't know what value the code variable should have in the request.

This is the section of code:

```
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  console.log ("Value of window.location.search", window.location.search);
  const code = urlParams.get('code');
  console.log ("Valor de code", code);
  const redirect_uri = "http://localhost:3000/formacionProf"
  const client_secret = clientSecret;
  const scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
  let access_token= "";
  let client_id = clientID;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    data: {
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      client_secret: client_secret,
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      grant_type: "authorization_code"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(resultData) {
      localStorage.setItem("accessToken",resultData.access_token);
      localStorage.setItem("refreshToken",resultData.refreshToken);
      localStorage.setItem("expires_in",resultData.expires_in);
      window.history.pushState({}, document.title, "/formacionProf");
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
  });
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: any reason why you arent using the library? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you are working on is the callback url from google api, so they will pass the parameters like "code", when they redirect to your page.

```
window.location.search
```

means the query string in current url. So maybe you need to do testing by redirecting from their pages.